# How to set up DB codes for forms

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a page that has 39 check boxes. The check boxes in my example resemble form names. My problem is that with 39 check boxes I need a way to store what forms were given to a student. Currently what I have set up is that each form is separated with a comma and a quote so that when a report is run the Administrator can use a CSV download option and group which forms a student has received. This works but is very rudimentary and also gives a bad side affect that before each form name a / is present because mysql escapes quotes.

This is what I currently have :

```
 if ($this->input->post('action') == 'additional') {
     $givenforms = "";

     foreach ($this->input->post('form') as $forms) {
      $givenforms .= ', "' . $forms . '"';
        }
        $comments = 'This student was given' . $givenforms . '';

        if (($this->input->post('action') == 'additional') && ($this->input->post('other') == 'OTHER')) {
            $comments .= ', '.$this->input->post('counselorcomments');
        }
 }
```

Again in the database the results will look like : This student was given "xyz", "eoe", "wwo",

Pretty much I just need ideas on how to store which forms a student was given, and if needed if all 39 forms are given to a student I need to store all forms the student was given for later reporting. (even though 39 forms wont be given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An hour or two of refactoring what I had with the CSV paid off quite well. I am very very pleased with the reporting/analytical possibilities of the knew information and the way I got it stored now.

Couple snippets of code for any one else looking into doing something like this! :

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { // This stuff is self explanatory RT(F)M if you will :) 
     $this->cont();
 } else {
     $this->load->model('queue_model'); // Load model

     $session = $this->uri->segment(3); // Gets the session id 
     $counselor = $this->session->userdata('username'); // I get counsellor names from the username they log in by joining between the two tables

      if ($this->input->post('action') == 'Additional') { // If additional forms is checked do the following 

      foreach ($this->input->post('form') as $form_id) { // for each form submitted take the session Id from above and insert it into the table forms with the foreach $form_id variable
          $this->queue_model->forms($session, $form_id);
      }

      if (($this->input->post('action') == 'Additional') && ($this->input->post('addother') == 'addotherinfo')) { // If forms were submitted and a addotherinfo was [checked] add comments 
          $comments = ''.$this->input->post('action'). ' - '.$this->input->post('counselorcomments').'';
      } else {
          $comments = $this->input->post('action');
      }
}
```

Also adding in a forms table (with the ID's and form names) allowed me to dynamically make the check boxes like so :

```
<?php 
        foreach ($elevennine as $form) { ?>
              <label id="form"><input type="checkbox" name="form[]" value="<?php echo $form['form_id'] ?>" <?php echo set_checkbox('form', $form['form_id']) ?>><?php echo $form['forms'] ?></label>
<?php   } 
?>
```

Thanks for all the great ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a one:many relationship between students and forms. Might want to do a little research on that topic.

I consider it generally to be pretty poor form to store comma separated values in a single field in a database, if you're doing that, it's almost always a sign that you need (at least) another table.

Comment: Using comma separated values in a single filed and then exploding it by the separator to create array in PHP is one solution, but as jcorry said is kind of poor design.
Still, it is a solution; if you know that will limit the flexibility of  your app, and having many-to-many intermediate table is overkill.

Comment: Right absolutely I do not like that design what so ever, just my problem is, not how to set it up (I'm quite familiar with database schemas and relationships) its pretty much when I set up a table with forms 1 - 39 if a student is given forms 1-10 how am i supposed to mark that in the student table? That is what is confusing me. I don't know how to have it so that multiple Numeric digits that are also related to anther field in the same column and row. I will look into this matter further!

Comment: You store the association between forms and students in another table: students_forms. That table as an id, student_id, form_id. There is a row for each student form. You can join forms to students on that table. You should get quite familiar with this technique, as it's pretty much central to database design.